# Semantic Issue :- Unused Parameter error

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, xcode8

I am getting this error:

[image: I am getting this error]

I have done the setting in Project in Build setting:

[image: I have done the setting in Project in Build setting]

I have done the setting in Target in Build setting:

[image: I have done the setting in Target in Build setting]

[image]

I have used the following solution

1) #pragma unused(parameterName), which is working

But the problem is, I have used too many file Where this error is coming, so I want to know if any common solution is available for this.

(*) any one can try the below steps to find this kind of error: **sample-videochat-webrtc**

1. Create swift Project
2. Add file, import and build then error will come

Comment: Sumit, your steps to reproduce are quite unclear. I tried to follow them without success. So if you want to get an answer, either provide a sample project that reproduces that issue or at least clear steps to reproduce.

Comment: @SergGr please Download demo Form This link:-  ( https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/archive/master.zip )
And open sample-chat-swift demo and after find " UsersViewController " And define a function -(void)getUserToName:(NSString *)strName{}

Then you will get error Parameter unused.

Comment: I still don't get it. UsersViewController is not a part of "sample-chat-swift" project so how should I open it? And if I open "sample-users" project of which [UsersViewController](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/blob/master/sample-users/sample-users/UsersViewController.m) is a part and add such a function, everything compiles just fine.

Comment: @SergGr okay if you not able to found then  please add a objective c file  declear  a function  with a parameter like this  -(void)getUserToName:(NSString *)strName{} and then check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, finally I was able to reproduce the issue on the sample project. This issue is a result of the fact that in the "sample-chat-swift" project among "Other Warning Flags" there is `-Wextra` flag (you can see it in [project.pbxproj](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/blob/master/sample-chat-swift/sample-chat-swift.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj#L611)) which according to [Diagnostic flags in Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wextra)

> Also controls -Wignored-qualifiers, -Winitializer-overrides, -Wmissing-field-initializers, -Wmissing-method-return-type, -Wsemicolon-before-method-body, -Wsign-compare, **-Wunused-parameter**.

And since the flags from "Other Warning Flags" are added after explicitly configured flags to the command line, `-Wextra` overrides `-Wno-unused-parameter`.